# colums alignement in JQuery Datatable (th width and td width are not the same)

Tags: jquery, header, width, alignment, datatables

My problem is when a cell of my table is too long (the text fit in several lines) the width of my header and the width of the rest of td are un-aligned...that's strange. Any idea?

there is my call function:

```
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    oTable = $('#tabloid').dataTable({
                        "aaSorting": [], 
                        "bJQueryUI": true,
                        "bPaginate": false,
                        "bAutoWidth": true,
                        "sScrollY": "500",
                        "sScrollX": "90%",

                        "bScrollCollapse": true, 



                        "sErrMode" :  'throw', 

                        "oLanguage": {
                            "sLengthMenu": "Voir _MENU_ lignes par page",
                            "sZeroRecords": "Aucun résultat à afficher",
                            "sInfo": "",
                            "sInfoEmpty": "",
                            "sInfoFiltered": "(filtré sur _MAX_ lignes totales)",
                            "sSearch" : "Chercher", 
                            "oPaginate" : {
                                "sFirst" : "|<<",
                                "sLast" : ">>|",
                                "sNext" : ">",
                                "sPrevious" : "<"
                            }
                        }       
                    });

                    new FixedColumns( oTable );
                } );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have fixed columns table why don't you switch off bAutoWidth and set column with for each column like in this example: http://live.datatables.net/#javascript,html,live